# Does an application, extension, or website for finding JSON element IDs exist?

Tags: json, macos, web, google-chrome-extension

I googled a bit with no luck. I'm wondering if a tool exists that allows a user to paste in a chunk of valid JSON, click on any of its elements, and get returned the id (path) to that element. I prefer either a web app, a Chrome extension, or a OSX or X11 app. Windows would be last resort as I'd have to run it under Crossover. I could also use a FireFox extension though I'd prefer Chrome.

The application would work like so, if I pasted in:

```
{"accounting":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","age":23},{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Smith","age":32}]"sales":[{"firstName":"Sally","lastName":"Green","age":27},{"firstName":"Jim","lastName":"Galley","age":41}]}
```

and clicked on 'Sally', it would return: employees.sales[0].firstName

There are some similar tools for XML that I've tinkered with over the years on various platforms. Anyone know if anything like this exists for JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of answering my own question here, I just found that you can do this in a bit of a roundabout way using the [Firebug Addon for FireFox](http://getfirebug.com/). If you enable the Net tab, and then browse the JSON data, then right-click the element and choose "Browse in Dom Tab", you can then right-click on an element and choose "Copy Path."

I'll keep poking around and see if I can find anything for Chrome, etc.

EDIT: updated instructions for Firebug.